# Revelency of asynchronous operations on memory streams

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, mono, memorystream

I am using a library (in C#, with mono 3.0) which uses a stream to serialize data, but synchronously. I would like to build an asynchronous network library over, by giving a memory stream to the serializer, and then sending this stream to a network stream asynchronously.

My question is, is it ok to use synchronous methods on a memory stream, since no I/O operations should be involved ?

Comment: from the comments below, it seems it would do much good if you reword your question and add some code samples. as it stands, the question is a simple yes/no question to which my answer is yes. now, you need to better explain the actual codes doing the NetworkStream, MemoryStream, Synchronous and Asynchronous operations. you can even draw a rough diagram and paste its link here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is perfectly ok to make asynchronous calls to memory streams, or in general, to either of IO or CPU bound activities.

to quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719598%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> ... a program can call a method, which enumerates a large list, while the main program continues to execute ...

just make sure that no two threads start accessing the memory stream parallely

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am asking if I can replace multiple I/O calls on a NetworkStream by calls on a MemoryStream, and then call the NetworkStream asynchronously, so that I don't have to modify the code base which is using synchronous methods, but give it a MemoryStream in place of the NetworkStream.